# how to hide the selection of the button in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

when i press the button i get the blue color ,
is there any way to just avoid getting that blue color when i press the button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sets the button look to be consistent regardless of the state

```
[UIButton1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonBack.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateHighlighted];
[UIButton1 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: nice. i didn't realise that these were bitmasks. This changes a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You could add a background image of the button for the state `UIControlStateHighlighted`. The background image would be the same as the non-highlighted state.